# I have a text file with multiple lines. How can I extract a portion from each line using regex in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The line input is like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf
```

Required output is:

```
25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf
```

which is `size`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute` and `filename` respectively.

The question asks to return a list of tuples `(size, month, day, hour, minute, filename)` using regular expressions to do this (either `match`, `search`, `findall`, or `finditer` method).

My code that I tried is -

```
for line in range(1):
```

```
    line=f.readline()
```

```
x=re.findall(r'[^-]\d+\w+:\w+.*\w+_*',line)
```

```
    print (x)

My output - [' 21:25 add_colab_link.py']
```

Comment: This appears to be a homework question. If so, Stackoverflow has a rule that the person asking the question must demonstrate that they have attempted to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: I tried doing it with first line only initially also Ignore the multiple prints as I was trying to see where I am heading-f=open("C:\Sneha_Python\hy-data-analysis-with-python-spring-2020\part02-e02_file_listing\src\listing.txt","r")

for line in range(1):
    line=f.readline()
    print(line[1])
    
    x=re.findall(r'[^-]\d+\w+:\w+.*\w+_*',line)
    regex=re.compile('[a-z][0-9]',re.IGNORECASE)
    y=regex.findall(line)
    print(y)
    print (x)

I got output as- [' 11:50 add_colab_link.py']
Not the entire line, I am a beginner.

Comment: Please modify your question instead, as code doesn't format properly in comments as you can see.

Comment: Sorry but this is the format of the line. There are multiple lines like this. Each line has seven fields. To make it clear I will add a comma after each word. But that is not the original format though.
-rw-r--r-- 1, jttoivon, hyad-all, 25399, Nov 2, 21:25, exception_hierarchy.pdf

Comment: can you edit your question and format code as code?

Comment: I understood what's your input, and also what's your output. Please edit your question to include what you have tried, using proper code formatting (this is unreadable as a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example using regular expressions thanks to package `re`:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf"
>>> pattern = r"([\d]+)\s+([A-z]+)\s+(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})\s+(.+)$"
>>> output_tuple = re.findall(pattern, line)[0]
>>> print(output_tuple)
('25399', 'Nov', '2', '21', '25', 'exception_hierarchy.pdf')
>>> size, month, day, hour, minute, filename = output_tuple
```

Most of the logic is encoded in the raw `pattern` variable. It's very easy though if you look at it piece by piece. See below, with new lines to help you read through:

```
([\d]+)    # means basically group of digits (size)
\s+        # means one or more spaces
([A-z]+)   # means one or more letter (month)
\s+        # means one or more spaces
(\d{1,2})  # one or two digits (day)
\s+        # means one or more spaces
(\d{1,2})  # one or two digits (hour)
:          # looking for a ':'
(\d{1,2})  # one or two digits (minute)
\s+        # means one or more spaces
(.+)       # anything basically
$          # until the string ends
```

By the way, here's a working example not using `re` (because it's actually not mandatory here):

```
>>> line = "-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf"
>>> size, month, day, hour_minute, filename = line.split("hyad-all")[1].strip().split()
>>> hour, minute = hour_minute.split(":")
>>> print(size, month, day, hour, minute, filename)
25399 Nov 2 21 25 exception_hierarchy.pdf
```

Comment: It is very well explained by you..amazing..thanks a ton. However, I have a question-How come using '\d{1,2}' does not pick digit 1 in "-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all" in the output? Just trying to understand how reg ex work. Do they work in a particular sequence/order?

Comment: You're welcome. If you were to look with `pattern = r"\d{1,2}"` you would indeed end up also retrieving the digit `1` in `-rw-r--r-- 1`. But in my given pattern, you're not looking only for a 1-2 digit pattern, you're looking for a sequence of patterns in a given order indeed. Regular expressions take into account the order given inside the pattern. You may have fun testing by yourself using tools like https://pythex.org/ (which is how I came up with the pattern by the way). If that answer suits your needs, don't hesitate accepting it please!

Comment: See https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D&test_string=-rw-r--r--%201%20jttoivon%20hyad-all%20%20%2025399%20Nov%20%202%2021%3A25%20exception_hierarchy.pdf&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: @SNEHA did that work out for you? Please accept the answer if it did. Best,

Answer (score 0):

```
import re  # import of regular expression library

# I just assume you had three of those pieces in one list:
my_list = ["-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 12345 Nov 2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf", "-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 25399 Nov 2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf", "-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all 98765 Nov 2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf"]

# I create a new list to store the results in
new_list = []

# I produce this loop to go through every piece in the list:
for x in my_list:
    y = re.findall("([0-9]{5}.+pdf)", x) # you can check the meaning of the symbols with a simple google search
    for thing in y:
        a, b, c, d, e = thing.split(" ")
        g, h = d.split(":")
        z = (a, b, c, g, h, e)
        new_list.append(z)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was helpful but the output formatting is changed particularly for time even though you have given (:) split.

Comment: welcome. Not sure though what you mean with the time as the output corresponds to the output you wanted. Anyhow, I am sure you can adjust as you see fit.